# Image Caching with PHP

Tags: php, caching

i am trying to learn how to cache an image that is created in PHP, this current piece of PHP wil cache text to a file, but i want to get it to cache an image called 'my_barcode.png' to the cache folder, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$h = opendir('data/');
$chace = 'cache/test.cache.php';

if(file_exists($chace))
{
include($chace);
}
else
{
$result = NULL;
while (($file = readdir($h)) !=false)
{
$result .= $file. '<br />';
}

closedir($h);

echo $result;

$fs = fopen($chace, 'w+');
fwrite($fs, $result);
fclose($fs);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can anyone help, is it something to do with echoing the result that is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to serve cached files, PHP should create them when not existing but the http server (such as Apache) should be serving the static files if they exist. Implementing cache the way you did takes too many resources as PHP is still called.

Comment: Hi Collector, i have apache installed. i create different images in my other php script, but im not sure how to cache them and call/get them. Can you help?

Comment: Haven't used Apache in a while. I'm sure there's a way to configure Apache to serve a static file and if it doesn't exist, go to a relevant script. Good luck